how to translate routes on angular 18 with built-in i18n
I'm building an Angular 18 application and need to implement routing with language-specific paths. I want to use Angular's built-in i18n (internationalization) features to translate route paths based on the selected language (e.g., /en/login, /fr/se-connecter). How can I configure my routes to dynamically translate paths based on the current language, using Angular’s built-in i18n?
Could someone provide guidance or best practices for achieving this in Angular 18? :)

Have you tried using the $localize function? { path: $localize\login` }`

yes, I do this, my app is loading forever.
thanks for helping

the built-in-i18 create different applications and simply change the base href. in the docs is explained

yes I saw the video @Eliseo. I was  wondering if it's possible. I didn't find a way to do it in Angular 18

I possibly fixed the bug where I cannot reach my app (like I said earlier loading forever)
but now I'm not getting correct translations. Like it's still those by default (english)
